# Facebook app users notifications

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-apps

I'm wondering, is it possible to notify every user of a Facebook app?

This is what I would like to do:
Let's say I have a Facebook app with 20 000 users and there is new content in the app. Is it possible to send out a message, wall post, notification, .. to each and every user to let them know there is new content without being banned by Facebook?

grtz,
bundy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track all the users (and their friends) by id who view the app. If you have prompted the user for the app to allowing posts/sharing etc you can post to users and their friends walls usin those ids. However there is a limit (My account got blocked for a couple of days for for sending approx 600 "Shares", by mistake ..logic error that kept posting... and the app was in sandbox mode, so the rules still apply)

So to answer the question, I would say No. not by wall posts/shares, but you could collect their email address and send them a mail externally with a link to the app.

My experience of FB is using the javascript api to create notifications and posts, I am not sure of the limits in this api and do get confused between "feeds", "Shares", "Notifications" etc... FB is not quite an exact science, it would seem.